# Built-custom editor with custom intellisense popups and syntax highlight

Tags: editor

Do you know any resources how to built custom editor with custom intellisense popups and syntax highlight? I'm searching the one similar to SciTE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of open source IDEs out there that you can check the source code for.

- [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)
- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/)
- [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

They all support syntax highlighting and intellisense (do different degrees).